# rlang::exec with package-specification for the function

Tags: r, rlang

I am having trouble getting `rlang::exec()` to work when I specify the package for a function call.

Simple examples:

```
rlang::exec("tibble" , a=1:5) # this fails because package 'tibble' is not yet loaded.
# Error in tibble(a = 1:5) : could not find function "tibble"

library(tibble)
rlang::exec("tibble" , a=1:5) # now it works.

rlang::exec("tibble::tibble" , a=1:5) # this fails.
# Error in `tibble::tibble`(a = 1:5) :
#  could not find function "tibble::tibble"
```

Ultimately, I am looking to include a command like this in an R package that I am making. It would be like this:

```
foo <- function(stuff , fun , args) {
    # do stuff, and then:

    rlang::exec(fun , !!!args)

    # do more stuff.
}
```

and  I want the user to be able to pass a function from a specific package. Something like this:

```
foo(stuff = whatever , fun = "pkg::fun" , args = list(a=1,b=2) )
```

And the user should be able to do that without first loading package `pkg`, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this by using `rlang::call2` to construct your expression before evaluating it with `base::eval`, rather than using `rlang::exec` which both constructs and evaluates the expression at the same time. `call2` has an argument `.ns` which allows you to define the namespace in which to look for the function, i.e.:

```
base::eval(rlang::call2("tibble", a = 1:5, .ns = "tibble"))
```

or in your last example

```
base::eval(rlang::call2("foo", !!!args, .ns = "pkg"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a tryCatch?

```r
foo <- function(stuff , fun , args) {
  # do stuff, and then:
  
  tryCatch(rlang::exec(fun, !!!args), 
           error=function(e) rlang::exec(eval(parse(text=fun)), !!!args))
  
  # do more stuff.
}

foo(stuff = whatever , fun = "+" , args = list(a=1, b=5) )
#> [1] 6
foo(stuff = whatever , fun = "tibble::tibble" , args = list(a=1:5))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>       a
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> 4     4
#> 5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Alternatively, you could ask your users to input `tibble::tibble` instead of `"tibble::tibble"`.

```r
foo <- function(stuff , fun , args) {
  # do stuff, and then:
  
  rlang::exec(fun, !!!args)
  
  # do more stuff.
}

foo(stuff = whatever , fun = "+" , args = list(a=1, b=5) )
#> [1] 6

# this will not work
foo(stuff = whatever , fun = "tibble::tibble" , args = list(a=1:5))
#> Error in `tibble::tibble`(a = 1:5): could not find function "tibble::tibble"

# this does!
foo(stuff = whatever , fun = tibble::tibble , args = list(a=1:5))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>       a
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> 4     4
#> 5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: but isn't part of the point of `rlang::exec` that you do not have to call `eval(parse())` ?

Comment: yes, that's why you could actually ask your users to pass `tibble::tibble` to the function instead of `"tibble::tibble"`

Comment: it doesn't require `enquo` or some of that confusing "quosure" stuff?

Comment: nope, I just tried. I've updated the answer to show you.